# Using Google as IdP in sandbox - how does it know what user to login to?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Question: How does a sandbox knows to which user to login?

Background: I have enabled SSO on a sandbox in order to test before going to produciton.
Our IdP is Google.
I have created a test user in Google OU, and enabled the SAML app to that OU.
In SF, I setup the new SAML SSO settings.

I log to: my-domain--sb.my.salesforce.com - that redirects me to the google login.
When I try to login, I get the error:

> ```
> Error: app_not_configured_for_user
>
> Service is not configured for this user
> ```

I am not sure if this error comes from google or SF.

In google SAML audit log I get the follwoing

```
> test user failed to login because of the following error: Application
> not configured    Failed login    test user       /SAML_Salesforce    Service
> provider  Application not configured          5.29.1.1    Apr 30, 2020,
> 6:41:49 PM GMT+3
```

- There is no login history in SF for the user.

What I don't understand is where in the process I tell SF what username to use for the login?
I tried to put on the 'Federation Id' field on the username, but got the same error.

What setting am I missing? *Since I am sure the proess works, and it's me with the error

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_saml_idp_values.htm&type=5 talks about config on SF side which determines the mapping

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simple answer is that Federation ID tells the service the connection between the IdP and salesforce.
meaning, even if you have the same email for several users, only one can have SSO at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from Google. Please read [Salesforce cloud application](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6194938?hl=en) and follow all of the steps. This includes "installing" and "activating" an app in Google in order to allow access. Unfortunately, we will likely not be able to help you with this error, as the problem is within your Google configuration, not Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you, I have followed through. The questions is still valid. How do I tell SF which user to log to? assume I can have the same email on 2 different users in the same org.

Comment: @Saariko SSO always uses a Federation ID, not the Username or Email fields.